# mysql query taking 1+ minute to complete

Tags: php, mysql

this query

```
 SELECT * FROM kp_landing_page lp
            WHERE lp.parent = '7' AND (
                SELECT COUNT(*) FROM kp_landing_page_product lpp
                    WHERE lpp.landing_page_id = lp.landing_page_id
                      AND lpp.productid = '6176'
            ) != 0
```

is taking around 1+ minute to complete, I tried rewriting it like this

```
 SELECT * FROM kp_landing_page lp
            INNER JOIN (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM kp_landing_page_product lpp
                  WHERE lpp.landing_page_id = lp.landing_page_id
                    AND lpp.productid = '6176') != 0
            WHERE lp.parent = '7'
```

While this is much quicker (3-4 seconds) it doesn't get met the required data I need, even though all tables remain the same, and executing this query inside of phpmyadmin givems me the same data as the old one. it just gives me the following error

```
The current selection does not contain a unique column. 
  Functions such as raster edits, checkboxes, Edit, 
  Copy and Delete are not available.
```

Any idea on how to optimize this? doesn't have to be insanely fast just now 1+ minute slow.

EDIT

Running explain on the old query

```
EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM kp_landing_page lp WHERE lp.parent = '7'
          AND ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM kp_landing_page_product lpp
                    WHERE lpp.landing_page_id = lp.landing_page_id
                      AND lpp.productid = '6176' ) != 0
```

gives me the following

```
1 id
PRIMARY select_Type
lp table
ALL type 
NULL possible_keys 
NULL keys
NULL key_len
NULL ref
233 rows
Using where extra
---
2
DEPENDENT SUBQUERY
lpp
ref
landing_page_id
landing_page_id
4
kerstpakketonline.lp.landing_page_id
437
Using where
```

EDIT 2

some more information

this piece of code (PHP) is where the slowdown happens

```
    $landingPages = array();
    $qGetMainPages = $connection->query("SELECT *
             FROM kp_landing_page WHERE parent = 0");

    foreach ($qGetMainPages->rows as $mainPage) {
        $qGetSubPages = $connection->query("
            SELECT  lp.* FROM kp_landing_page lp
            WHERE lp.parent = '" . (int)$mainPage['landing_page_id'] . "' AND (
                SELECT COUNT(*) FROM kp_landing_page_product lpp
            WHERE lpp.landing_page_id = lp.landing_page_id 
               AND lpp.productid = " . (int)$row['productID'] . "
            ) != 0
        ");


        foreach ($qGetSubPages->rows as $subPage) {
            $landingPages[$mainPage['title']][] = $subPage['title'];
        }
    }
```

seems to be executing x amount of queries foreach product thus causing o(n) issues?

EDIT 3

using `SHOW CREATE TABLE on both tables`

-- kp_landing_page_product

`kp_landing_page_product CREATE TABLE kp_landing_page_product ( id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, landing_page_id int(11) NOT NULL, productid int(11) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id), KEY landing_page_id (landing_page_id), KEY productid (productid), CONSTRAINT landing_page_id_2 FOREIGN KEY (landing_page_id) REFERENCES kp_landing_page (landing_page_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=522630 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8`

-- kp_landing_page

`kp_landing_page CREATE TABLE kp_landing_page (  landing_page_id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,  title varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,  title_multi varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,  rewrite varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,  active tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,  parent int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,  ordering int(11) NOT NULL,  show_as_filter tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,  popular tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, color_code varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_bin NOT NULL,  PRIMARY KEY (landing_page_id) ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=247 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_bin`

kp_landing_page_product contains 160854 total rows

kp_landing_page contains 233 total rows

kp_landing_page returns 9 rows using this
`SELECT * FROM kp_landing_page WHERE parent = 0` query

kp_landing_page_product returns around 40 rows using this

`SELECT * FROM kp_landing_page lp WHERE lp.parent = '7' AND ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM kp_landing_page_product lpp WHERE lpp.landing_page_id = lp.landing_page_id AND lpp.productid = '6176' ) != 0`
query, this can change depending on productid supplied

Comment: What gives that error?  It doesn't appear to be a MySQL error.

Comment: If lp.parent is an integer, why are you using `'7'` instead of just 7?

Comment: What does the execution plan tell you? Maybe you are missing indices?

Comment: @ysth PHPmyadmin gives that error

Comment: @SalmanA that's just because the query is build dynamically with PHP

Comment: @NicoHaase no missing indexes, using EXPLAIN

Comment: Then please share the execution plan, and more details that could help to check for problems

Comment: 1. Alright, I ran EXPLAIN again with the old query `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM kp_landing_page lp WHERE lp.parent = '7' AND ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM kp_landing_page_product lpp WHERE lpp.landing_page_id = lp.landing_page_id AND lpp.productid = '6176' ) != 0
`

Comment: the subquery tells me I can set a possible key on `landing_page_id` on the `kp_landing_page_product ` table, but this is already set as index

Comment: And what's the result of that `EXPLAIN` call? Please add all clarification **to your question** by editing it. Don't use the comment section for important stuff

Comment: @nielsvanhoof dynamic or not, datatype should match. Does removing the quotes help?

Comment: @SalmanA nope, doesn't change anything. I edited my question with some more info, seems to be o(n) problem, not sure how to solve this

Comment: How often does that query get executed? Why not use a proper `JOIN` such that you don't have to run new queries in a `foreach` loop?

Comment: File is a cronjob, it runs every 30 minutes. How would you write it to a proper join?

Comment: @SalmanA - `'7'` is just as good as `7`'  (The opposite is not good:  `WHERE string_column = 7` -- this needs to convert each string to a number.)

Answer (score 1):

Indexes:

```
lp:   INDEX(landing_page_id)
lpp:  INDEX(landing_page_id, productid)  -- either order is OK
```

Use EXISTS (aka "semi-join") instead of

```
      AND (
            SELECT COUNT(*) FROM kp_landing_page_product lpp
                WHERE lpp.landing_page_id = lp.landing_page_id
                  AND lpp.productid = '6176'
        ) != 0
```

-->

```
 AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM kp_landing_page_product AS lpp
                WHERE lpp.landing_page_id = lp.landing_page_id
                  AND lpp.productid = '6176' )
```

`EXISTS` will stop when the first one is found; `COUNT(*)` probably has to do more work to find out the exact count.

(If you desire further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for the two tables, the size of each table (approx number of rows) and the number of rows returned by the query.)

Comment: Hey, using your `AND EXISTS` ... query gives me an error  `#1064 - There is something wrong in the syntax used at ''in line 5`, Also I'll update my post with your required information

Comment: Show me the query as you have it now.

Comment: `   SELECT * FROM kp_landing_page lp 
         WHERE lp.parent = '" . $mainPage['landing_page_id'] . "'
           AND EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM kp_landing_page_product AS lpp
                WHERE lpp.landing_page_id = lp.landing_page_id
                  AND lpp.productid = '" . $row['productID'] . "' )`

Comment: I a WHERE clause before the `AND EXISTS` otherwise I would get a syntax error

Comment: @nielsvanhoof - No.  `WHERE` can have two "expressions" `AND'd` together.  `EXISTS ( SELECT ... )` is an "expression".  Something else must be wrong.  Let's see the query after PHP finishes putting it together.